# Recovery from multiple disk failure using RAID level-6

Tags: raid

How to find a RAID level 6 scheme with ten disks such that it is possible to recover from the failure of any three disks simultaneously?

Actually the question is from the book: Database System Implementation by Hector Garcia-Molina (exercise: 2.6.13)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the different widely used RAID levels and when should I consider them?](http://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them)

Answer (score 2):

RAID 6 consists of block-level striping with double distributed parity. So, it tolerates two disks failures only (one more disk than Raid 5).

In summary, it is not possible for Raid 6 to survive three disk failures. Increasing number of disks to ten (for example) just adds more capacity and does not improve availability (redundancy).

Comment: Actually the question is from the book: Database System Implementation by Hector Garcia-Molina (exercise: 2.6.13)